# Handling a user with multiple accounts?

Tags: support

It appears that a recent visitor to the History stack, "basque-spaniards", is creating a new account for each visit. I've seen at least 4 accounts but there may be others...

https://history.stackexchange.com/users/16674/basque-spaniards
https://history.stackexchange.com/users/16895/basque-spaniards
https://history.stackexchange.com/users/17133/basque-spaniards
https://history.stackexchange.com/users/17134/basque-spaniards

From the style, language and content these all appear to be owned by the same author and, from the usage, I imagine that they aren't intentional sock-puppet accounts.

Can these be merged into a single account? What's the best way of contacting this user to inform them how to use a single account for all of their questions and answers?